# How to share a session in j2ee application?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, session, tomcat, jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to share session state between different applications in tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665941/any-way-to-share-session-state-between-different-applications-in-tomcat)

How can i share a **session  Attribute** in 2 web project in the same work space ?

i read that the session is on the server why when i go the 2nd project in the same work space i dont find any session Attribute .

i mean i cant use that in the énd project

```
<%
                        if(session.getAttribute("UserName") != null ){

                        %>

        do Some work 

        <% } %>
```

i'm usign Tomcat V7 as a server 
and eclipse

Comment: The basic answer is: you cannot share a session between two webapps. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Also, a workspace is an Eclipse thing. It doesn't have any meaning  for Tomcat, which is where the application runs. Tomcat knows about web apps, not workspaces.

Comment: @ mkro : i have a web project application and web service i had a prbm with creating a hibernate in the web service and i dont have time so i finish my web application in 2nd web project , i have left one jsp file must be in the web serviceClient so i want to use a session in this jsp file to access it from the web app

Comment: @ JB Nizet : sir go see the server.xml of tomcat and you will find the path of the work space and the path of the web project

Answer (score 1):

hmmm! if you are using tomcat you can set crossContext=true in server.xml i.e.

```
<Context allowLinking="true" docBase="/home/appA" path="/appA" reloadable="true"  crossContext="true"/>
<Context allowLinking="true" docBase="/home/appB" path="/appB" reloadable="true" crossContext="true"/>
```

and then you can share the sessions, also if you can tell me the situation then I might be more helpful

Comment: i have a web project application and web service i had a prbm with creating a hibernate in the web service and i dont have time so i finish my web application in 2nd web project , i have left one jsp file must be in the web serviceClient so i want to use a session in this jsp file to access it from the web app , thank you so mutch for you answer

Comment: sir i try this like that

Comment: <Context allowLinking="true" docBase="F:/workspacetravailProject/HiberBarti" path="/HiberBarti" reloadable="true"  crossContext="true"/>
<Context allowLinking="true" docBase="F:/workspacetravailProject/SpeedyServiceClient" path="/SpeedyServiceClient" reloadable="true" crossContext="true"/>

Comment: when i add this to server.xml the server wont start , whyyyyy?

Answer (score 0):

i try to do what the answer say so i change them like that

```
 <Context docBase="SpeedyService" path="/SpeedyService" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpeedyService" crossContext="true"/><Context docBase="HiberBarti" path="/HiberBarti" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HiberBarti" crossContext="true"/><Context docBase="SpeedyServiceClient" path="/SpeedyServiceClient" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpeedyServiceClient" crossContext="true"/></Host>
```

but i found a 2nd file service.xml in my work space i didnt change

```
<Context docBase="F:\workspacetravailProject\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ROOT" path="" reloadable="false"/><Context docBase="F:\workspacetravailProject\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpeedyService" path="/SpeedyService" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpeedyService"/><Context docBase="F:\workspacetravailProject\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\HiberBarti" path="/HiberBarti" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HiberBarti"/><Context docBase="F:\workspacetravailProject\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpeedyServiceClient" path="/SpeedyServiceClient" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpeedyServiceClient"/></Host>
```