# Sharing security context between few web applications

Tags: spring, security, web

I need to have web application which actually consist from few separate wars unified into same navigration bar on UI, i need to have all system secured but have authentication only to main web application and after automatic propagation of this security context to sub web applications. I'm using spring security, could someone help me with advice? thanks

Comment: Please clarify - are yours WARs are packaged into single EAR?

Comment: nope, its absolutely separate wars in same servlet container, I just need to propagate authentification to them after user loggined into main application, first thought is security token on cookie but its seem not so robust

Comment: Either way it seems that you should use CAS (see in Spring docs for that)

Comment: Need to mentions that all those WARs are starting like bundles in OSGI container

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Security stores the login data in the http session. So what I would try is to share the session between the applications.

It seams that this is possible (in Tomcat) by using the [Single Sing On](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Single%20Sign%20On) attribute.

But be warned, sharing the session between two applications is not without danger. See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665941/any-way-to-share-session-state-between-different-applications-in-tomcat).

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved by following approach. In Spring, `SecurityContext` by default is stored in `HttpSession`. Instead you can configure it to store in some shared repository.

So, configuration should be changed to use your own `SecurityContextRepository` implementation instead of `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`. Once configured, the security framework will look at the `Repository` which is available to all your web applications.

The `Repository` can be either a database or a cached server.