# can i share session in this way

Tags: java, jsp, session, webserver

Currently I have this problem:
I have two apps, like

## ipaddress:port/app1    ipaddress:port/app2

These two apps can't share session from each other.
So I think if i merged these two apps into one, like

## ipaddress:80/app/app1          ipaddress:80/app/app2

and using a web server(i'm intending to use IHS) to make a proxy. So the final address will be

## ipaddress:portproxy/app1           ipaddress:portproxy/app2

> My question is that can I make these two url being able to share session in this way

Comment: Probably yes, but sounds like a lot of work. Why do you want to share a session anyway? When you say "share session" do you want to be able to single sing in? Is there anything else?

Comment: Yes, it's a single sign on problem, but in different policy, so I need to share sessions to check the status of user. And the app2 only contains this one jsp, very easy to merge, so i think this may works. @Yori Kusanagi

Comment: For single sign-in I always hear about Kerberos and oAuth. You can also try shared objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665941/any-way-to-share-session-state-between-different-applications-in-tomcat