# Session sharing between different webapps in Jetty

Tags: java, spring, session, cookies, jetty

I have two webapps loaded from one embedded jetty server. Both apps are using Spring MVC. 
Sessions are managed by manipulating HttpSession objects in the controller methods.
(request.getSession() and session.invalidate(), etc)

But suppose a user signs in on web app A, and session is created on web app A. When the same user hits web app B, can the app read and recognize the same session that's being used in A? Or do two web apps have completely separate session managements? I see the browser stores a JSESSION cookie, so I wonder if two apps would use the same JSESSION cookies?

I did search around and had no luck, probably related to embedded jetty having mutliple apps is a bit uncommon.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665941/any-way-to-share-session-state-between-different-applications-in-tomcat) in scope of tomcat, but looks like the same is possible for [jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/using-jetty-jndi.html)