# Global Filter for all Web Applications

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, websphere

In a J2EE application, how do I create a global Filter that can access other webapps installed on that app server?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still interested, here are my findings regarding this question:

1. For tomcat and others webapp servers derived from it (eg: JBoss), you can add your filter to the "global" web.xml, usually located under $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml.
2. For Websphere, I´ve found the following article to be useful: http://www-03.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/WebIndex/WP101859 . In this case, the basic idea is that you write a ServletContext Listener and uses it to attach your filter to the app

Answer (score 1):

The Servlet-API does not provide such a security leak. But some containers offer alike. Have a look at the `<Valve>` Configuration of Apache Tomcat. Maybe there is a similar functionality for webshere, but typically you need to hire a ibm consultant to "find" the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Some application servers/servlet containers (Tomcat, JBoss) provide the cross context feature.  It does depend on what you're running your application within however, it's not a J2EE feature.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html

I'm not sure whether this will help you in what you want to do.  What is it exactly? : )

Take a look at this response as well:

[What does the crossContext attribute do in Tomcat? Does it enable session sharing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661978/what-does-the-crosscontext-attribute-do-in-tomcat-does-it-enable-session-sharing)

Comment: Like JBoss, Websphere also uses Tomcat under the hoods and if I recall my rusty Websphere experiences correctly, the very similar `crossContext` setting is just available at Websphere. This way you could create a webapp which runs on the ROOT and run the filter on `/*`. But again, that's the theory, I can't confirm this from own experience. Alternatively you could declare the filter in appserver's own `web.xml`. +1 for the hint regardless :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in a container/platform independent way.  Your J2EE container might provide hooks for you to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8815211/964681

*Sorry, couldn't just comment on your question. Haven't enough "points".*