# JBoss 4: where do I deploy global filters?

Tags: servlets, jboss, servlet-filters, jboss-4.2.x

I want to use "global" HTTP filters.

Therefor, I edited `deploy/jboss-web.deployer/conf/web.xml` and added:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>StatisticsFilterHitCount</filter-name>
    <filter-class>myapp.StatisticsFilterHitCount</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>StatisticsFilterHitCount</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now, when I start the server, not a single artifact can be deployed. A huge exception is logged on each deployment attempt. Sorry, can't paste it here. I suppose, at the time of deployment, the filter class is not present yet.

So, where (and how) do I have to deploy such filter globally?

Currently, it's in `applications/5apps`, the packaging is `.war`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `Jboss/server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/conf/web.xml`.
There is even an example of global CommonHeadersFilter.

But you would have to place the code in some jar under `JBoss/server/default/lib`. JBoss can't peek up the code in the war at web container's initialization process.

Comment: Great! It worked! In my case, the right destination for the artifact was `server/dorun/lib/`. Oh, and I had to change the packaging to `jar`.

Comment: Needless to say this no longer works in Wildfly (JBossAS 7+) since they switched from using Tomcat to using their own web container "undertow".

Answer (score 1):

If the class file is missing , just build it in . There should be a class with the name  StatisticsFilterHitCount inside the war under myapp package which implements the Filter interface , overrides

```
           doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException 

           init(FilterConfig filterConfig)

           public void destroy()
```

and does whatever it is meant to do . Check for this .

Comment: Yes, this class id definitely there, I wrote it. So that's not the problem ;) As I mentioned in the question: at the time when `deploy/jboss-web.deployer/conf/web.xml` is processed, my artifact (containing this class) isn't yet loaded (I assume).