# Configuring global filter in websphere 8.5

Tags: filter, websphere, web.xml

I want to register filter class for all web application in websphere; Tipically in tomcat I specify filter in /conf/web.xml. How can I do this in Websphere 8.5.

Also what is the common library (lib folder) in websphere. The filter class is in jar file and I want to put that jar file in websphere server lib directory.

-Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do it in WebSphere. It was already discussed here - [Global Filter for all Web Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24433840/3701228)

WebSphere solution involves creating custom listener and programmaticaly attach filters. You can find sample solution and description here - [Adding a servlet filter to all web applications](http://www-03.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/WebIndex/WP101859)

> What is the common library (lib folder) in Websphere?

You can put your jar to `WebSphere\AppServer\lib\ext` directory to be shared by all profiles, servers and apps, or create a shared library via web console `Environment > Shared libraries` and attach it to the specific server or application.