# Setting up proxy filter for all application on WebSphere Application Server

Tags: java-ee-6, websphere-7, websphere-8

We have multiple Java EE applications running on WebSphere Application Server 8.0. We want to write a filter for the entire set of applications running on WAS.

This filter will have access to the current `HttpServletRequest` targeted to the web application. It could add new request headers and finally add some additional cookie information in the response.

Are there any extensions provided by WAS that allow us to do this?

This is kind of a proxy filter for the entire set of application running on WAS.

Comment: There is no such mechanism in WebSphere. It was already discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070091/configuring-global-filter-in-websphere-8-5)