# Java Filter not working on production environment Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, websphere

I have a filter used for authorization. It's the first step entering application. Without it is not possible to do anything in the application.

I set a systemout on the very first line of doFilter method to monitor the behaviour, so comparing websphere server log files I'm sure that filter (same Ear deployed) on Test environment works and on Production environment not.

Maybe it's server configuration issue...?

I have access to read and modify WAS Console of test environment.

I have access only to read WAS Console of production environment.

So I can compare them, and maybe test some change on test environment to replicate the behavior and say to production administrator what exactly setup....

Any suggestion on which setting I can check (Was console, maybe in relation with Web.xml, etc...)?

Thx a lot for any suggestion.

EDIT

I was able to retrieve via FTP the EAR in InstalledApps of Production environment. I noted a file named "web_merged.xml" in which is missing the entry of the filter.

Maybe the problem is here? When is created and why? Why could be missing the entry there? How let WAS to create the right file (if the problem is there)?

Comment: Are you using IBM WebSphere Portal or IBM WAS?

Comment: ...IBM WAS, thx, any info/idea is appreciated

Comment: Which web server are you using? If not IBM WebSphere portal, you can check this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070091/configuring-global-filter-in-websphere-8-5

Comment: Make sure you're comparing ear files obtained the same way from both environments. Maybe try using the WAS admin console to download the production ear, then deploy that to the test environment and see how it behaves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the one on the EDIT in the question, webmerged.xml was wrong. We weren't able to understand why WAS generated this file in wrong way.

What I understand is generated during deploy and is a mix of web.xml of the applicatin with application server configuration.

That's a WebSphere issue, we guessed it has to do with application server cache. We asked to System Administrator to:

- Uninstall the application
- Stop the server in which the application was installed
- Clear the cache
- Restart the server
- Reinstall application

From this point the file was generated in the right manner, as the application bahaviour.

Websphere version is 8.5