# Tomcat: How to share data between two applications?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat5.5

Is there any way to share data between to JSP applications using Tomcat 5.5?

The applications are running in the same server.

The shared data should not persist in the system for many time and cannot be stored in cookies because it's bigger than 4Kb.

Thanks! 
:)

Comment: What do you mean by 'sharing'?
Something that can not be accomplished via database connection or webservices?

Comment: No something like a session attribute for all server applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the data in a file on the disk file system or a database server which both have access to.

---

**Update**: as per the update and the comments, the functional requirement seems to boil down to let the webapps on the same server share the same `HttpSession` (including all of its attributes). In that case, you need to set the `emptySessionPath` attribute of the [`<Connector>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) element in Tomcat's `/conf/server.xml` to `true`.

```
<Connector emptySessionPath="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the crossContext attribute to allow you to share data via the context object.  Previous Stackoverflow here:

[What does the crossContext attribute do in Tomcat? Does it enable session sharing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661978/what-does-the-crosscontext-attribute-do-in-tomcat-does-it-enable-session-sharing)