# shared objects between webapps of the same tomcat

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, tomcat6

I have 2 webapps running at two contexts: c1, c2 (both immediately after the root). I put a startupListener in c1 to share a variable, and another one in c2 to retrieve it.

My startuplistener in c1 is:

```
 public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {  
            HashMap <String,Object> database ;
            //some code to init database 
            ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext().getContext("/c1");
            if (context!=null)
            {
                context.setAttribute("crossContext", true);
                context.setAttribute("cache", database);
            }

    }
```

In c2 app, it is like this:

```
      public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext().getContext("/c1");
            HashMap<String,Object> database = (HashMap) context.getAttribute("cache");

      }
```

The context in the startupListener of c2 is always null, I've tried '/c1', 'c1'. What am I missing? 
(I'm using tomcat6, if that matters)
Thanks

Comment: Its the value retrieved which is null and not the context I guess?

Comment: no, the context is null, which triggers an NPE the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set crossContext=true. From the tomcat docs:

> Set to true if you want calls within this application to
>   ServletContext.getContext() to successfully return a request
>   dispatcher for other web applications running on this virtual host.
>   Set to false (the default) in security conscious environments, to make
>   getContext() always return null.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: Also see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661978/what-does-the-crosscontext-attribute-do-in-tomcat-does-it-enable-session-sharin

Comment: hey Brad, I did set crossContext to true in app c1.

Comment: if it's helpful to s/o else: Brad's answer is correct, but note the crossContext=true is set in the config/context.xml of your tomcat folder.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

There is mismatch in app initialization may be app2 is initialized before app1.

There is a potential "workaround": If you actually have two (or more) apps depending on each other, you may decide to start multiple services in you `server.xml:`

```
<Service name="app1">
  <Connector .../>

  <Engine ...>
     <Host appbase="app1" ...>
       ...        
     </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="app2">
  <Connector .../>

  <Engine ...>
     <Host appbase="app2" ...>
       ...        
     </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
```

Comment: Hi, I can confirm that c2 is always started after c1, I manually started them in order.

Answer (score -1):

One more option is use serialization. Serialize the data in one app and read the same in the other one.

Comment: the OP's asking about 2 webapps in same JVM, so serialization is unnecesary