# is it possible a java web application can call another java web application in same localhost of tomcat server

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, tomcat, seam

i am trying to deploy two web applications say appA and appB in same local host tomcat server and when the both the applications are up in running is it possible to call appB to appA using ajax call or redirect

Comment: Yes it is possible !!!! you need to get the context of appB  in appA .

Comment: Have you looked at HttpClient by Apache ? if they are servlet based (as you said web application), I think then you can use them to call get or post method.

Comment: can we do it seam frame work to respond to ajax call from another application with simple html or jsp page with out having any high level stuff

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for toa chieve can be done using the following  tomcat parameter:

(from docs)

**crossContext**

Set to true if you want calls within this application to ServletContext.getContext() to successfully return a request dispatcher for other web applications running on this virtual host. Set to false (the default) in security conscious environments, to make getContext() always return null.

example:

http://blog.imaginea.com/cross-context-communication-between-web-applications/

related discussions:
[What does the crossContext attribute do in Tomcat? Does it enable session sharing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661978/what-does-the-crosscontext-attribute-do-in-tomcat-does-it-enable-session-sharin)

Answer (score 0):

## Try This Way

```
ServletContext ctx = request.getServletContext().getContext("/otherapp");
request.setAttribute("MESSAGE", "Hello There!");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ctx.getRequestDispatcher("/hello.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

**Note**

> To enable this feature in Tomcat we need to enable the `crossContext`
> attribute by setting the value to `true`, the default value is `false`.