# Is it possible to access a public method of a java web application from another java web application?

Tags: java

If I have a web application with a class that contains a public method that returns data when called, is it possible to call such a method from another web application residing in the same server? Or do I have to use web services?

Comment: You need to give us some more information, exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160454/is-it-possible-a-java-web-application-can-call-another-java-web-application-in-s

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use socket connections to communicate between two different apps inside the same server, as you suspected.

[Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/socket-programming) is a link that may give you some guidance in case you need it.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: what have to do sockets with this? It seems  reinventing the wheel to me